# Can't update entity with unique constraint index in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, unique

I have an entity `Invoice` with 1 `Provider` and many `ParticularFieldValues`. In my  invoice I have a unique index constraint in attribute InvoiceNumber.

The problem is that I want to do minimal changes in `Invoice`, it throw an exception saying that I can't `SaveChanges` because of duplicated unique index `InvoiceNumber`.

I also tried with attach and it said that I cant because of the same duplicated.

Here is my table diagram:

[image]

[image]

Invoice class:

```
public class Invoice
{
        public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
        public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual int ProviderId { get; set; }
        public virtual Provider Provider { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ParticularFieldValue> ParticularProviderFieldsToComplete { get; set; }

        public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

        public int TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the operation I can't do:

```
public void UpdatePayment(Invoice inv)
{
            UnitOfWork.Invoices.Update(inv);
            UnitOfWork.Save();
}

public void Update(Invoice inv)
{
            Invoice invDb = base.Get(inv.InvoiceId);
            invDb.TotalAmount = inv.TotalAmount;
}

public TEntity Get(int id)
{
            return dbSet.Find(id);
}
```

And the exception:

> "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.",
>   "InnerException": {
>   "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>   "ExceptionMessage": "No se puede insertar una fila de clave duplicada en el objeto 'dbo.Invoices' con índice único 'IX_InvoiceNumber'. El valor de la clave duplicada es (123451).\r\nSe terminó la instrucción.",
>   "ExceptionType": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",
>   "StackTrace": "
>   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
>   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>
>   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)
>
>   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)
>
>   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>
>   en System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>
>   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
>   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   en
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   en
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\r\n   en
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\r\n   en
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2
>   identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)\r\n   en
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()

Comment: Check all your existing invoices, make sure the unique index constraint `InvoiceNumber` is auto-increment, or if you set it manually, make sure you are setting one which doesn't exist in the table already.

Comment: The thing is that I want to update the invoice with the same InvoiceNumber

Comment: what's the error when calling `Get(int id)`?

Comment: Check for EntityState. If you want to modify then that entity's EntityState must be Modified. In your case, it may be Added. Due unique key constraint, it is not allowing to add duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, it turned out that before updating the entity, I first tried to add it, and if the record was already there, then under certain conditions I changed this record. And at the time of adding, when the error popped up that the record already exists, I forgot to call the Detach on this entity in time, so when I later tried to update my property, the first thing DbContext tried to do was add an entity that already exists in db (because of this, the error about the unique index was caused), but it never got to the point of updating. In short, check whether you have summoned Detach from entities everywhere.